# ypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript

im done it exactly like in the tutorial and mine is not working, i cant guess why, thanks for any help

```
import React from "react";
import Day from './Day';

function Month({ month }) {
    return (
        <div className="flex-1 grid grid-cols-7 grid-rows-5">
            {month.map((row, i) => (
                <React.Fragment key={i}>
                    {row.map((day, idx) => (
                        <Day day={day} key={idx} />
                    ))}
                </React.Fragment>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Month;
```

Comment: What is the error ? Can you share where the Month Component is being used ?

Answer (score 0):

The `month` or the `row` object are undefined in your code try optional chaining to make sure that your objects are not undefined or null.

```
import React from "react";
import Day from './Day';

function Month({ month }) {
    return (
        <div className="flex-1 grid grid-cols-7 grid-rows-5">
            {month?.map((row, i) => (
                <React.Fragment key={i}>
                    {row?.map((day, idx) => (
                        <Day day={day} key={idx} />
                    ))}
                </React.Fragment>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Month;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably mapping something that is not an array
Be sure what you pass and read this page (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)